# Easiest way to query a SQL Server 2008 R2 XML data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to get a node value in an XML data type column.

```
<CustomContentData>
  <prpIsRSSFeed>false</prpIsRSSFeed>
</CustomContentData>
```

How is this done in SQL Server?

The column name is `ClassXML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column is already XML data type in SQL Server, then the code below should work by using the value function with XPATH. If it's stored as a varchar, you'd just need to replace `ClassXML.value` with `CONVERT(XML, ClassXML).value`. Hope this helps!

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (ClassXML XML)
INSERT @Data VALUES ('<CustomContentData><prpIsRSSFeed>false</prpIsRSSFeed></CustomContentData>')

SELECT
    CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN ClassXML.value ('(/CustomContentData/prpIsRSSFeed)[1]',
        'VARCHAR(50)') = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IsRssFeed
FROM @Data
```

**Yields output**

```
IsRssFeed
---------
0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [XQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx), a simple example with your data would be:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ClassXML XML);
INSERT @T (ClassXML) 
VALUES  ('<CustomContentData>
            <prpIsRSSFeed>false</prpIsRSSFeed>
        </CustomContentData>');

SELECT  t.ClassXML.value('CustomContentData[1]/prpIsRSSFeed[1]', 'VARCHAR(5)')
FROM    @T AS t;
```